# How to Use :date_started to Figure Out :levels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, integer

When a User starts a habit he chooses his `date_started` in the form.

How can we use `date_started` as the start point to figure out and display in the index what `level` the User is on?

A certain amount of days must pass before the User moves onto the next level (as shown below in the **model**).

Currently when a User looks at the index all his habits will show "Mastered" regardless of what the `date_started` is. Thanks in advance for your expertise =]

**form**

```html
      <label> Started: </label>
      <%= f.date_select :date_started, :order => [:month, :day, :year], class: 'date-select' %>
```

```html
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates :action, presence: true
 serialize :committed, Array

 scope :missed, -> { where(missed: 1) }
 scope :nonmissed, -> { where(missed: 0) }

 def levels
   case committed
   when 0..9
     1
   when 10..24
     2
   when 25..44
     3
   when 45..69
     4
   when 70..99
     5
   else
     "Mastered"
  end
 end
end
```

**controller**

```html
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
   @habits = Habit.all.order("date_started DESC")
   @missed_habits = current_user.habits.missed
   @nonmissed_habits = current_user.habits.nonmissed
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @habit = current_user.habits.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @habit = current_user.habits.build(habit_params)
    if @habit.save
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @habit.update(habit_params)
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @habit.destroy
    redirect_to habits_url
  end

  private
    def set_habit
      @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @habit = current_user.habits.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
    end

    def habit_params
      params.require(:habit).permit(:missed, :left, :levels, :date_started, :trigger, :action, :target, :positive, :negative, :committed => [])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def levels
  n_days = Integer(Date.today - date_started)

  case n_days
    when 0..9
      1
    when 10..24
      2
  ...
  end
```